# Issues with notification pending intent in Samsung device

Tags: java, android, android-pendingintent

When we send `Parcelable` class in pending intent then Samsung device which have Android version 10 or 11 it receives `null` in receiver activity

What is the problem in only Samsung devices?

```
// sending putextra

Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnswerJavaActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.INCOMING_CALL_INVITE, callInvite);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, notificationId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// receiving code sample
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_answer);
handleIncomingCallIntent(getIntent());
}
 private void handleIncomingCallIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "handleIncomingCallIntent-");

            String action = intent.getAction();
            activeCallInvite = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.INCOMING_CALL_INVITE);}}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Show some more code around where the receiving code is received and handled.

Comment: and what calls `handleIncomingCallIntent`?

Answer (score 0):

Custom `Parcelable` objects have always been a problem, as often the "extras" need to be decoded by code that is in the Android framework and it doesn't know how to decode your custom objects. There are 2 possible solutions:

Wrap your custom `Parcelable` with a `Bundle`. Sometimes this works as the Android framework doesn't have to unwrap the `Bundle`.

Alternatively, you need to serialize (convert) your custom object to a `byte` array and put that in the `Intent`.